# Rails: How to get column value if present in history?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have 3 tables,

**Issues**

```
|id|subject|done_ratio|
-----------------------
|1 |test   | 50       | 
|2 |test1  | 0        | 
|3 |test3  | 10       |
```

**Journals**

```
|id|issue_id|notes|created_on         |
---------------------------------------
|1 |1       |NULL |2017-09-29 16:35:09|
|2 |3       |test |2017-09-28 16:35:09|
```

**Journal Details**

```
|id|journal_id|prop_key  |old_value|value|
------------------------------------------
|1 |1         |done_ratio|0        |50   |
```

Basically, there are 3 models.

**Issue**

```
has_many :journals
```

**Journal**

```
belongs_to :issue
has_many :journal_details
```

**JournalDetail**

```
belongs_to :journal
```

`Journals` and `Journal details` tables are being used to maintain `Issue` history.

If some attribute of issue is updated, a `journal` entry is created along with `journal details` for each updated attribute. And if just a note is added to `issue`, only `journal` entry is created with that note.

How can I fetch list of issues along with the *value of `done_ratio` before today or `0` if not found?*

I can fetch all the issues first and then *fetch `done_ratio` value before today in separate queries* for each issue.

**finding issues**

```
issues = Issue.all
```

**finding done_ratio before today for each issue**

```
journal = issue.journals.joins(:details).where("journal_details.prop_key ='done_ratio' AND DATE(journals.created_on) = ?", Date.today).order('journals.created_on asc').limit(1).first
last_done_ratio = journal.details.where(prop_key: 'done_ratio').first.old_value.to_f unless journal.blank?
```

but that will increase load time. So, i want to do it in one query.

**Coalesce may work here but don't know how.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do u have associations between these models. if so, put them here so that I can give solution

Comment: Updated question and added associations.

Comment: can u show how you are fetching data ?

Comment: updated question again. plz check.

Comment: Doesn't Issues table has created_at column? Can't you use that to get all issues before today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find list of issues along with the value of done_ratio before today with the following query:

```
Issue
  .joins(journals: :journal_details)
  .where(journal_details: { prop_key: 'done_ratio' })
  .where("DATE(journals.created_on) = ?", Date.today)
  .order('journals.created_on asc')
```

It wont return the issues which don't have journal details with `prop_key` 'done_ratio' associated with them. If you need to get issues with no 'done_ratio' details also then you need to use `OUTER JOIN`:

```
Issue
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN journals ON issues.id = journals.issue_id")
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN journal_details ON journals.id = journal_details.journal_id")
  .where(journal_details: { prop_key: 'done_ratio' })
  .where("DATE(journals.created_on) = ?", Date.today)
  .order('journals.created_on asc')
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this:

```
Issue.select('issues.id, issues.subject, journal_details.old_value as done_ratio')
  .left_outer_joins(journals: [:journal_details])
  .where('journal_details.prop_key = ?', 'done_ratio')
  .where('journals.created_at < ?', Time.now)
  .order('journals.created_at DESC')
```

But this is not works like you need.
I'll leave it here so people will know how not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This plain SQL query may helps you to achieve with the desired result.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/54dcb/3

```
SELECT i.id,  COALESCE(done_ratio,'0')
   FROM    issues i left join ( 
          select j.issue_id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY j.created_on desc) AS rank_index,
                 jd.new_value done_ratio
            FROM Journals j 
      inner join journal_detail jd 
              on j.id = jd.journal_id 
             AND jd.prop_key = 'done_ratio' -- We are interest only in 'done_ratio' only
             AND j.created_on < CURRENT_DATE -- and which changed before today -- TODO check for time precision
    ) last_day_done
ON i.id = last_day_done.issue_id and rank_index = 1 --Only join with first row (most recent)
```

This may required you to create additional indexes on tables.